# How to create custom page for category and single page for specifed category with its children in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, blogs

I want to create custom page for category and single page for specifed category with its children .

**First** , to create custom single page i've used this code

```
if (in_category('blog')){
include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-blog.php');
}elseif(in_category('projects')){
    include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-projects.php');
}
else{
    include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-default.php');
}
```

and it work fine just for specifed ctegory in the code and doesn't support the children of category.

fo example : i would like to use `single-blog.php` for single page of posts that its category is `blog` or `children of blog` .

**Second** , for category page i want to do the same things that i've explained above for list of category's posts .

fo example : i would like to show the list of posts that is related to blog category or its children in `category-blog.php`.

how can i do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the **first** part of your question, you're probably looking for [`cat_is_ancestor_of`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/cat_is_ancestor_of), so you'd write something like this:

```
function is_ancestor_of( $ancestor_category ) {
    $categories = get_the_category(); // array of current post categories
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        if ( cat_is_ancestor_of( $ancestor_category, $category ) ) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$ancestor_category = get_category_by_slug( 'blog' );
if ( in_category( 'blog' ) || is_ancestor_of( $ancestor_category ) ) {
    // include
}
```

For the **second** part, I understand that you want to do the same thing but for an archive page. In that case, it's a bit simpler as you won't have an array of categories:

```
$archive_category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) ); // current archive category
$ancestor_category = get_category_by_slug( 'blog' );
if ( is_category( 'blog' ) || cat_is_ancestor_of( $ancestor_category, $archive_category ) {
    // include
}
```

Let me know if this works for you,

**EDIT** - Here's an alternative option (not tested) that doesn't use --at least directly-- a `foreach` loop. Not sure if it's higher performance though.

```
$ancestor_category = get_category_by_slug( 'blog' );
$children_categories = get_categories( array ( 'parent' => $ancestor_category->cat_ID ) ); // use 'child_of' instead of 'parent' to get all descendants, not only children

$categories = get_the_category(); // array of current post categories

if ( in_category( 'blog' ) || ! empty( array_intersect( $categories, $children_categories ) ) {
    // include
}
```

Comment: thanks ,Pol . it works like a charm ,but i wish there were another way that doesn't use foreach because it's a little low performance

Comment: @Hamed you might want to test my edit to see if it performs better, i'm not sure

Comment: @Hamed Just tested it... and you're right. FYI, there appear to be a couple of problems: **(1)** for some reason `get_the_category()` appends an extra `object_id` property to the category objects, so they differ from `$children_categories`; this can be resolved by using `$categories = get_categories( wp_get_post_categories( get_the_ID() ) )` instead. However,  **(2)** `array_intersect` doesn't seem to work with arrays of objects. You could get around this limitation, but at that point the first answer will probably perform better.